# MVC, AngularJS, Generate a random setup of added notes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to create a solution, where I can input names into a textarea and then generate a setup of notes (where each note has two inputfields) with a random order but in the newest added notes.
I have tryed so many things now without success. I really hope some of you can help me out or maybe point me to a simular example.

For example, if I put in four names in the textarea and then presses "Generate Notes", it should generate three notes where the first note should show up empty in both fields and the names will be put into the last two notes in random order. Like this:

Textarea;

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

The output will be like this:

> 1. [empty,empty]
> 2. [name2,name3] [name1,name4]

If I put in six names:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
```

The output would be like this:

> 1. [empty,empty]
> 2. [empty,empty] [empty,empty]
> 3. [name2,name5] [name3,name1] [name4,name6] [empty,empty]

The following fiddle has a none-functioning textarea added. It does has a "Generate Notes" button that right now manually adds notes. One session per click. It doesnt generate anything.

Please take a look at this fiddle:

```
jsfiddle.net/VJ94U/1140/
```

Any help or directions you are able to give me are much appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your problem specifically: if you are looking for a generic algorithm it is not related to angular, however if you know how to solve the issue but not how to implement it, tell us what you don't manage to do. Randomly sort an array? Count the right number of items to insert?..

Comment: Hi Floribon - excellent question! I am not sure how to count the items that is needed to be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so you're looking for an algorithm that solve this situation. Here is a working example, now you need to adapt that to Angular thingies, let us know if you have problem with that.

```
function graph(nbNames) {
  var nbLines = 0;
  while (Math.pow(2, nbLines) < nbNames) { nbLines ++; }
  for (var i=0; i<nbLines; i++) {
    var t = '';
    for (var j=0; j<Math.pow(2, i); j++) {
      t += '[ ';
      for (var k=0; k<2; k++) {
        if (i === nbLines-1 && (j*2+k) < nbNames) { t += ' x '; }
        else { t += ' - '; }
      }
      t += " ]";
    }
    console.log(t);
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
graph(4) >>
[  -  -  ]
[  x  x  ][  x  x  ]

graph(6) >>
[  -  -  ]
[  -  -  ][  -  -  ]
[  x  x  ][  x  x  ][  x  x  ][  -  -  ]
```

EDIT: And you can get your array of names from the textarea this way:

```
var names = $(yourTextArea).val().split('\n');
var numberNames = names.length;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Floribon. It definitely solved my issue of the correct algorithm! Thanks again.